# Errors were encountered while processing: linux-headers-6.1.0-kali5-amd64 linux-image-6.1.0-kali5-amd64 linux-headers-amd64 linux-image-amd64?

Tags: kali-linux

Kali won't let me fully upgrade. The error I get when I try is:

```
Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j2 KERNELRELEASE=6.1.0-kali5-amd64 -C /lib/modules/6.1.0-kali5-amd64/build M=/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.12/build...(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.1.0-kali5-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.12/build/make.log for more information.
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 failed!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.1.0-kali5-amd64 (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.1.0-kali5-amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-amd64:
 linux-headers-amd64 depends on linux-headers-6.1.0-kali5-amd64 (= 6.1.12-1kali2); however:
  Package linux-headers-6.1.0-kali5-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-amd64:
 linux-image-amd64 depends on linux-image-6.1.0-kali5-amd64 (= 6.1.12-1kali2); however:
  Package linux-image-6.1.0-kali5-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.1.0-kali5-amd64
 linux-image-6.1.0-kali5-amd64
 linux-headers-amd64
 linux-image-amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I checked the make.log file and saw this:

```
DKMS make.log for virtualbox-guest-6.1.12 for kernel 6.1.0-kali5-amd64 (x86_64)
Tue Mar 14 10:45:27 AM EDT 2023
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-kali5-amd64'
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.12/build/vboxguest/VBoxGuest-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.12/build/vboxguest/VBoxGuest.o
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.12/build/vboxguest/include/iprt/types.h:34,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.12/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/the-linux-kernel.h:37,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.12/build/vboxguest/VBoxGuest-linux.c:36:
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.12/build/vboxguest/include/iprt/stdarg.h:47:12: fatal error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
   47 | #  include <stdarg.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.12/build/vboxguest/include/iprt/types.h:34,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.12/build/vboxguest/VBoxGuestInternal.h:33,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.12/build/vboxguest/VBoxGuest.c:54:
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.12/build/vboxguest/include/iprt/stdarg.h:47:12: fatal error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
   47 | #  include <stdarg.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-kali5-common/scripts/Makefile.build:255: /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.12/build/vboxguest/VBoxGuest-linux.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-kali5-common/scripts/Makefile.build:255: /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.12/build/vboxguest/VBoxGuest.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-kali5-common/scripts/Makefile.build:505: /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.12/build/vboxguest] Error 2
make: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-kali5-common/Makefile:2030: /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.12/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-kali5-amd64
```

This is a VirtualBox VM. I am using `sudo apt full-upgrade -y`. I am trying to upgrade to Kali Purple which is 6.1.0-kali5-amd64

Update: Tried to install missing stdarg.h with `sudo apt-get install libc6-dev` but it outputs the same dpkg error

Comment: Looks like you're missing header files.

Comment: A little clarification... with "code brackets `{ }`" I was referring to the symbol on the top bar of the edit box, between blockquote and image link. Click on the question mark on the top right corner of the edit box to get an explanation of the top bar markup buttons.

Comment: @Shadur tried to install with sudo apt-get install libc6-dev but it outputs the same dpkg error

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running VMWare but was having the same issue.

**DISCLAIMER**

I don't know if aufs-dkms will be required for you, so I recommend taking a snapshot before taking the following steps.

First, boot into the previous kernel version. Then, I was able to fix it with:

```
sudo apt remove aufs-dkms
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade -y
```

After those steps, I was able to reboot into the new kernel.

Comment: did the code and it outputs: dpkg: error processing package linux-image-amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.1.0-kali5-amd64
 linux-image-6.1.0-kali5-amd64
 linux-headers-amd64
 linux-image-amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: The way I found aufs-dkms was causing an issue was by trying to install each of these one by one:
```Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.1.0-kali5-amd64
 linux-image-6.1.0-kali5-amd64
 linux-headers-amd64
 linux-image-amd64
```
It gave me the error:
```Error! The /var/lib/dkms/aufs/5.2+20190909/6.1.0-kali5-amd64/x86_64/dkms.conf for module aufs includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which does not match this kernel/arch/config.```

Maybe try a similar approach and see what's breaking?

Answer (score 0):

Your `virtualbox-guest` is version 6.1.12, which was released [back in July 2020](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog-6.1#v12) - and at that time, the 6.x kernel series did not even exist yet.

No wonder the DKMS is failing to build the `virtualbox-guest` modules for that kernel!

In order to support Linux 6.1.x kernel series, you'll need to first update VirtualBox to at least version [6.1.42](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog-6.1#v42) (= the latest VirtualBox 6.1 series release at the time of this writing) or [7.0.2](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog-7.0#v2) (= the VirtualBox 7.0.x series release that added Linux 6.1 kernel series support).

Once you have done that, you must then update the VirtualBox Guest tools within the VM, and only after that you should be able to re-run the Kali update.